# Rewriting locale URLs in Apache to a single endpoint

Tags: mod-rewrite

I currently have a number of URLs all at

```
/book[...whatever]
```

As part of a localisation project we are looking to localise those with a prefix:

```
/en/book[...whatever]
/es/book[...whatever] # etc...
```

How can I use mod_rewrite to keep those localised URLs in the browser but map them to the underlying /book[...whatever] URLs?

Comment: What else indicates which locale they should be directed to? If the `/en` or `/es` prefix is present, does that actually make a difference in the resource targeted?

Comment: In other words, do both of  `/en/book/123` and `/es/book/123` actually just refer to `/book/123` without any localization?

Comment: The resource target is the same. I've got a solution but I'm sure it could be optimised - I'll post that now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I'm guessing there's a way to reg exp this to a single condition:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(en/book(.*)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /book/%2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(es/reservar(.*)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /book/%2 [L]

# etc for other locale IDs and book verbs
```

EDIT:

So this appears to achieve it as a one-liner for each of the 5 languages we have in scope:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^((en/book|es/reservar|fr/reserver|de/buchen|it/riservare)(.*)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /book/%2 [L]
```

Comment: Oh - your original question has `/en/book` and `/es/book`, not `/es/reservar`.  That makes a difference and was the reason for my questions.

Comment: Ah sorry - misinformed! I've got another solution now - will update the answe